# Why the loop is not breaking and also the if condition isnt working as expected?

Tags: c++

```
#include"std_lib_facilities.h"
int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  int len_password;
  cout<<"How Long Should Be Your Password?\n";
  while(i == 0){
    cin>>len_password;
    if(!cin && len_password > 15){
      cout<<"Please enter an appropriate value:\n";
    }
    else{
      break;
      cout<<"success!";
    }
  }
}
```

I want this code to print success when the loop breaks...and the loop will only break if the condition in if statement is satisfied....but even after typing the right input the loop is not breaking and also when i enter wrong input it is not allowing me to input once again...

Comment: But what exactly do you check in that condition?

Comment: `cin` won't return any useful value. You don't need `!cin`. Also print success **before** the break

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to print "success" *before* breaking out of the loop. Also, your check for `!cin` doesn't make sense.

Instead, you could check if the `cin` operation failed, and if so, you can clear the stream to take additional input:

```
while(!(std::cin >> len_password) || len_password > 15)
{
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  std::cout << "Please enter an appropriate value:\n";
}

cout << "success";
```

The loop will keep executing until the user enters an appropriate value, and then "success" is printed outside the loop. This avoids any `break` statements within the loop.

Comment: but if the user inputs string it is still printing success.....

Comment: the above code is still printing success even if i type a string......please check...

Comment: I wasn't checking for invalid input, and clearing the stream. It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

If you checking it's less then 15 then print should be before the break and you don't need the !cin

Comment: !cin is to check whether the user has entered integer or a string....if they enter any alphabets then it will be wrong